# Convexity of constrained profit function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have to show that the following constrained profit function, $\pi$, is convex.

A firm choses non-negative quantity, $x$, of inputs with price $p$ and non-negative quantity, $y$, of outputs with price $q$ subject to a production possibility constraint $G(x,y) \leq 0$.

$$ \pi (q, p) = \max_{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+}{qy - px}$$

subject to the following production possibility constraint:
$$ G(x,y) \leq 0 $$

How would you proceed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you think of a way to decompose the inner function $qy-px$ to the sum of two functions? What do we know about the sum of convex functions? What do we know about the maximum of a convex function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let: \begin{align}
\pi&=f\circ g \\
f(x,y)&=\max\{g(x,y)\} \\
g(x,y)&=g_1(x)+g_2(y) \\ 
g_1(y)&=qy \\
g_2(x)&=-px
\end{align}
Then $g_1,g_2$ are linear and therefore convex. $g(x,y)$ is convex as the sum of convex functions.

Finally, $\pi(q,p)$ is convex as the maximum of a collection of convex functions is convex. In our case this collection is a single function.

Comment: Take $G(x,y) = 0$ if $ ||(x,y)||<1$ and $\infty$ otherwise, then $\pi$ doesn't exist if $p>0$ or $q<0$.

Comment: What are you taking about man? It's a shame you're trying to confuse the person asking the question. We say that a function is convex over a convex set. If $G(x,y)$ is linear, than we can have an equality constraint and the feasible set is still convex. If  $G(x,y)$ is convex but not linear, we must use inequality constraints. Draw a circle on a piece of paper and you'll get it. If the constraint set is not convex there is no meaning to the convexity of a function. It doesn't mean it's not convex, it's just meaningless.

Comment: Exactly, that's why my answer is the way it was. Compactness and convexity aren't incidental to questions about optimization, they're important considerations.

Comment: Whatever man, you're just here to argue. You could have given me a thumbs up for a short and elegant proof, and maybe admit you learnt something new. You chose to try and confuse people. We'll let the person asking the question decide

Comment: Also, if $G(x,y)$ is just a finite set of points (and therefore non-convex), $\pi(p,q)$ will still be piecewise linear and convex. There are many cases where a non-convex constraint set leads to a continuous and convex $\pi(p,q)$.